# putting quotation mark after searching a string

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have the following information:

```
gene            complement(297183..300379)
                 /Name="Sp34_10006520"
                 /EC_number=3.2.1.45
gene            334670..335559
                 /Name="Sp34_10007100"
                 /EC_number=4.2.1.17
```

I want the output like this:

```
gene            complement(297183..300379)
                 /Name="Sp34_10006520"
                 /EC_number="3.2.1.45"
gene            334670..335559
                 /Name="Sp34_10007100"
                 /EC_number="4.2.1.17"
```

I want to put the "" marks after finding the `/EC_number=`. Please guys help me out

Comment: this is the 3rd question today related to file with `gene`... how about trying to solve yourself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
sed 's/EC_number=\(.*\)/EC_number="\1"/' file
```

Or:

```
sed -E 's/EC_number=(.*)/EC_number="\1"/' file
```

Or:

```
perl -pe 's/(EC_number=)(.*)/$1"$2"/' file
```

Or:

```
awk -F= '/EC_number/{$2="\""$2"\""}1' file
```